# I am getting $ajax is not define even though I have added src. Below is my html file content

Tags: ajax

Below are my script tags

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#delete').click(function(){
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata = formdata.append('id',selected);
            $ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/delete",
                data: formdata,
                success:function(){}
            });

        });
    });
```

I am trying to call my javascript function to send ids of the selected images but when I am calling that function I am getting $ajax is not define error. It would be much helpful if someone could help me, Thanks!

Comment: Where do you think `$ajax` is defined?  It isn't in the posted code.

Comment: <footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</footer>

Comment: come on, you can't see that you are missing a "." between "$" and "ajax"?? it's `$.ajax(...)` have you even tried to search on google?

Comment: Thanks @Berto99 mate. I have just started learning javascript. Thank you again for your help

Comment: no problem, but please, before asking, try searching on google, there are a lot of great resources on the web...